# Github Action stuck on running executable

Tags: c++, github, msbuild, github-actions, googletest

I'm trying to setup running `google tests` on a `C++ repository` using `Github Actions` that are running on `Windows Latest`.
The building process completes, but when it comes to running the tests - it is stuck and doesn't execute the executable, that is generated from the `Visual Studio Project` via `msbuild`. Generally the tests should execute in a close to none amount, since there are not a lot of tests. I have also waited and 30 minutes for the action to execute, but no luck.

What I have tried is:

1. Running the executable straight from the `actions.yml` file like:

- `Build/Tests.exe`
- `Build/Tests`
- `./Build/Tests`
- `./Build/Tests.exe`
- `cd Build && Tests.exe`
- etc.

Some of these commands run and execute locally, but are stuck on execute on the `Github Actions Runner`.
Now I have switched to a python script running these commands for maybe getting more insight on the process and seems when calling `subprocess.Popen`, the `action` is still stuck, but on `wait`.

Workflow callstack after canceling the workflow:

```
Run python Tools/test.py
  python Tools/test.py
  shell: C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.EXE -command ". '{0}'"
  env:
    CMAKE_VERSION: 3.21.1
    NINJA_VERSION: 1.10.2
    pythonLocation: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.10.2\x64
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\a\Lib\Lib\Tools\test.py", line 48, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "D:\a\Lib\Lib\Tools\test.py", line 44, in main
    return run(cmd_arguments)
  File "D:\a\Lib\Lib\Tools\test.py", line 39, in run
    return process.communicate()[0]
  File "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.10.2\x64\lib\subprocess.py", line 1141, in communicate
    self.wait()
  File "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.10.2\x64\lib\subprocess.py", line 1204, in wait
    return self._wait(timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.10.2\x64\lib\subprocess.py", line 1485, in _wait
    result = _winapi.WaitForSingleObject(self._handle,
KeyboardInterrupt
```

[image: Github action stuck on execution]

Comment: smells like some kind of undefined behaviour if your tests run on your machine but hang on another

Comment: Tried even different shells (cmake/bash/cmd)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `windows-latest` (`windows-2022` *currently at the time of writing*) by default no longer adds the necessary DLL paths in the environment variables.

- (https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/6103)
- (https://github.com/allanlw/hphpc-docker/issues/4)
- (https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/6412)

You might be able to solve this problem by adding it yourself manually or instead use an older version that have those paths by default `runs-on: windows-2019`